# Fake proof of the Axiom of Specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice, fake-proofs

I came up with a fake proof of the axiom of specification, but can't pinpoint exactly what's wrong with the proof.

Let $P$ be some logical formula which evaluates sets to true or false, and let $X$ be some set. I claim that there exists a set $S=\{x\in X\mid P(x)\}$.

By choice, we can well-order $X$. Thus, WLOG we can assume that $X$ is an ordinal. We now conduct transfinite induction to construct a function $\phi_X:X\to X+1$.

Base case: $\phi_0:0\to X+1$ is a function.

Successor Case: Given $\phi_\alpha:\alpha\to X+1$, let $\phi_{\alpha+1}$ be as follows:$$\phi_{\alpha+1}(x)=\begin{cases}\phi_\alpha(x)&x\in\alpha\\X&x=\alpha\wedge\lnot P(\alpha)\\\alpha&x=\alpha\wedge P(\alpha)\end{cases}$$Inductive Case: Given $\phi_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\gamma$, let $\phi_\gamma(x)$ equal $\phi_\alpha(x)$ for any $x<\alpha<\gamma$.

Thus, we have a map $X\to X+1$ whose image is $S\cup\{X\}$.

Now, we extend this map to a binary relation $R$ on **Set** by sending any set not in $X$ to itself. Thus, by the axiom schema of replacement, $R[X]=S\cup\{X\}$ is a set, and thus, so is $S$.

Comment: I am not an expert in logics, but I suppose that "by choice we can well order $X$" assumes the Axiom of Specification.

Comment: @Crostul As far as I can tell, [no](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Well-Ordering_Theorem)

Comment: @Crostul The well-ordering principle follows from choice together with $\Delta_0$-specification, a weak form of specification that is universally accepted, and power sets.

Comment: Replacing a well-ordered set with an ordinal is appealing to Replacement. Since Replacement implies Specification...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that is another problem. But you can still try to do the proof by using induction on the well-order itself rather than induction on the ordinal, so it's not the real problem.

Comment: @Mark: It's not induction, it's a recursion. And there's no reason to expect it to follow through at limit steps without assuming Replacement. The reason that we don't really need Replacement for transfinite recursion on a given well-order to work in ZF is that we can usually bound it inside a set and apply Specification. But we can't do it here, since that'd be circular.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is indeed the problem, as I explain in my answer.  I explain it in terms of induction rather than recursion, but the two are two sides of the same coin since each follows from the other (suitably phrased). Without specification and replacement, well-ordered recursion only works with a fixed codomain and a $\Delta_0$-formula to specify what happens in the case of 0, successors, and limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous problems here, but one of the most fundamental is in your use of transfinite induction and in your definition of $\phi$.

I will assume you're attempting to work without the axiom schemes of specification and replacement, since (over classical logic) replacement implies specification. I assume you're working instead with $\Delta_0$ specification (which states that if $\phi(x)$ is a formula where all quantifiers are of the form $\exists w \in a$ or $\forall w \in a$, then the set $\{x \in X | \phi(x)\}$ exists).

The problem is that well-order induction is dramatically weaker without full specification. In fact, well-order induction can only be used on $\Delta_0$ formulas.

For let us recall the principle of well-ordering induction(or, more generally, well-founded induction), which states that given a well-ordered set $(A, <)$, $\forall Q \subseteq A (\forall x \in A [(\forall y \in A (y < x \implies y \in A)) \implies x \in A]) \implies \forall x \in A (x \in Q)$.

The issue here is that we can only use well-ordering induction to show that $\forall x \in A, x \in Q$ for some subset $Q \subseteq A$. In other words, we must actually be able to define the subset $Q$ corresponding to the relevant property in order to be able to use well-founded induction.

Let's say we have some well-ordering $(A, <)$ and we want to show $\forall x \in A, Q(x)$. With full specification, we can pass to the set $Q = \{x \in A | Q(x)\}$ and use well-ordering induction on this set. But with only $\Delta_0$ specification, we require first that $Q(x)$ be a $\Delta_0$-formula in order to construct $Q = \{x \in A | Q(x)\}$ using specification.

The issue here is that the statement $Q(\alpha) :\equiv $ "$\phi_\alpha$ exists" is not a $\Delta_0$ statement, because saying whether a function satisfies the definition of $\phi_\alpha$ invokes $P(\alpha)$, which is not necessarily a $\Delta_0$ statement. Thus, you cannot apply well-founded induction here.